# Two way data binding between multiple dependent models in cascade form in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am writing code on Angular 2 including multiple dependent two-way binding models and need to bind those model in cascade form. On more specific, I have written data and code of a food selection with multiple dependent radio buttons.

**JSON data:**

```
{
  "DishId": "TestingDish",
  "ivDishTypes": [
    {
      "TypeId": "Chicken",
      "ivProductSizes": [
        {
          "SizeId": "Half",
          "Rate": 70
        },
        {
          "SizeId": "Normal",
          "Rate": 130
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "TypeId": "Fish",
      "ivProductSizes": [
        {
          "SizeId": "Half",
          "Rate": 60
        },
        {
          "SizeId": "Normal",
          "Rate": 110
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemType">
  <strong>Select Dish Type</strong>
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let productType of selectedDish.ivProductTypes;
   let idx = index" [value]="productType" [checked]="idx === 0">
    {{productType.TypeId}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemSize">
  <strong>Select Dish Size</strong>
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let productSize of selectedItemType.ivProductSizes;
   let idx = index" [value]="productSize" [checked]="idx === 0">
    {{productSize.SizeId}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**Component section:**

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    this.selectedDish = data.item;
    // These Item Type and Size is bounded with front end
    this.selectedItemType = this.selectedDish.ivProductTypes[0];
    this.selectedItemSize = this.selectedItemType.ivProductSizes[0];
}
```

By default radio button selection:

`selectedItemType =  Chicken` object & `selectedItemSize = Chicken.Half` object

When I click `Fish` radio button:

`selectedItemType =  Fish` object & `selectedItemSize = Chicken.Half` object

Here I am expecting `selectedItemSize = Fish.Half` object on component data section, but it shows `Fish.Half` selection on HTML only. Since I have used the first bound model property in second.

It's working only when I clicked both levels of the radio buttons.

Comment: Can you put together a stackblitz showing the behavior? It's a bit hard to follow just from this. Also, bare in mind that AngularJS and Angular are two different things. There is no AngularJS 2, it's just Angular, v2.*. Likewise, you want to use the Angular tag in SO to get the right people looking at it.